# Yosemite - Can't add text note at arbitrary position in Preview?

Tags: pdf, macos, preview

Previously, when selecting the "text" tool in preview in order to add a note to a PDF, I could specify where to add this text note by clicking on a particular place of the pdf before actually typing in. However now it seems to be not the case anymore: The text box automatically appears **exactly in the middle** of the current page. This is incredibly inconvenient as I have to drag the them around after typing to put them exactly in place. I can't believe they have dished out such an un-intuitive design. Is there a way to revert to the old fashion, or do I have to change software for PDF?

Comment: Is it a specific pdf  or any?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Any. I think I'm clear enough in my description...

Comment: so it is not recognizing your pointer position! is it only for text or for all inserts?

Comment: @Buscar웃 All inserts. Including notes, shapes, whatsoever. It just directly puts them in the middle of the page. So you say it's not how Yosemite is supposed to behave?

Comment: It looks as if Preview.app is falling even more behind as a PDF viewer. IMHO, Preview can not be used for anything beyond displaying very simple PDFs without any features (annotations, but also overprints and transparencies). The leader of the pack for PDF viewing is still Adobe Reader.

Comment: @MaxWyss Unfortunately Adobe Reader has been extremely slow and unusable on Mac, and I doubt anyone likes Adobe nowadays. Preview was actually really good except for its inability to change background of document. Now this doesn't look good.

Comment: @Anonj: Trust me, I know what I am talking about, and I have been suffering from the less than optimum performance on Mac for a decade. However, Adobe Reader is still the standard against which any PDF viewer is measured. It is absolutely irrelevant if you like Adobe or not (why otherwise would the "corporate" world still use MSOffice???). Also, I beg to differ about Preview.app. Preview.app DESTROYS PDF documents when saving. Forms filled using Preview.app become corrupted beyond repair, and it is apparently Apple's incompetence or unwillingness that this has not been fixed yet.

Comment: Preview is still the best PDF viewer on mac, even with these annoying bugs that were introduced by Yosemite.
(Super smooth scrolling, fast, many highlight colours, etc)
Please report this a a bug, here: https://www.apple.com/feedback/

Answer (score 1):

My formal answer to the question: Don't use Preview.app for anything beyond viewing simple PDF documents. In particular don't use Preview.app when you intend to save the document.

The obvious (and better) choice is Adobe Reader XI, which does at least not destroy a document when saving it.

Answer (score 1):

Well Adobe Reader's slow page scrolling is simply unbearable. In the end I decided to use [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/), which a lot of people seem to be using as default PDF viewer on OS X already. I'll only use Adobe Reader if I'm dealing with very important/complicated document, or if I want to change the background color of the document when I read.

EDIT April 2017: Now that Adobe Reader's efficiency seems to have been improved considerably, I just switched to it instead.

Comment: Skim seems good, but I want different colours for highlighting!

Answer (score 0):

Preview 7.0 has this capability. If you have a backup of your Mavericks installation you can copy Preview 7.0 into your Applications folder and it will coexist with Preview 8.0 (Yosemite).